# link a CSS file in a Freemarker file

Tags: java, html, css, freemarker

i've a problem with the insertion of ccs file in my .ftl file.
I try to do that:

```
    <head>
    ...
    <#include "resources/css/layout/grid.css">
    ...
    </head>
```

But my page display all the code inside my css file.

Can you help me pls?

(sry if my english is bad ^^')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are your `resources` folder and `.ftl` file in the same directory? If not, then you need to adjust the path accordingly e.g.

Replace

```
<#include "resources/css/layout/grid.css">
```

with

```
<#include "../resources/css/layout/grid.css">
```

if your `resources` folder is inside a folder which is one level up in the directory hierarchy.

For further help, please attach the screenshot of the directory structure showing the location of your `resources` folder and `.ftl` file.

Comment: Thanks you for your help !! It was it.